# OpenAI fine-tuning training data exceeds the token limit

Tags: machine-learning, openai-api, fine-tuning, curie

I am using curie model to fine-tune in Python. Basically, I am passing the training data of form `{"prompt":"completion"}` and I have 736 prompt-example pairs.
My example completions are pretty long - I aim at generating a JSON file based on a description of fixed form. The fine-tune reports to be created, however, when retrieving the fine-tune model key via

```
retrieve_response = openai.FineTune.retrieve(id="fine_tune_model_id")
print(retrieve_response)
```

I get the following messsage:

```
{
  "created_at": 1685346828,
  "events": [
    {
      "created_at": 1685346828,
      "level": "info",
      "message": "Created fine-tune: fine_tune_model_id",
      "object": "fine-tune-event"
    },
    {
      "created_at": 1685346879,
      "level": "info",
      "message": "Error: The training file does not contain enough examples that fit within the 2048 tokens allowed for this model.",
      "object": "fine-tune-event"
    }
...
```

and thus the status failed, but for the "training files" object the status is proceeded (pretty obvious).

Is there  a way  to overcome the error above?

I do have an OpenAI subscription.